# Removing objects from an ArrayList, as Part of 'Undo Move' feature Implementation for a 2D Array Board Game

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am trying to implement an undo move feature using Arraylist. I have created an Arraylist that holds Move objects, upon every valid move (‘U’, ’D’, ’L’, ’R’), it adds a new move object in the Arraylist. That is working properly, at this stage, I am currently trying to get it to remove the last object from the Arraylist, each time ‘Z’ is pressed but it only does one removal and any other subsequent presses of ‘Z’ does not change anything.

Can anyone please look at the code below and let me know what I am doing wrong?

The implementation/issue is in the move method, the last case in the switch statement.

```
package secondproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int INITIAL_PLAYER_COL = 0;
    private static final int INITIAL_PLAYER_ROW = BOARD_SIZE - 1;
    private static final int HOME_COL = BOARD_SIZE - 1;
    private static final int HOME_ROW = 0;
    private static final int WALL_LENGTH = 5;
    private static final char PLAYER_CHAR = 'P';
    private static final char HOME_CHAR = 'H';
    private static final char WALL_CHAR = 'X';
    private static final char FREE_SQUARE_CHAR = '.';
    private static final char DOUGHNUT_CHAR = '@';
    private static final char UP_MOVE_CHAR = 'U';
    private static final char DOWN_MOVE_CHAR = 'D';
    private static final char LEFT_MOVE_CHAR = 'L';
    private static final char RIGHT_MOVE_CHAR = 'R';
    private static final char UNDO_MOVE_CHAR = 'Z';
    private static final char TRAIL_CHAR = 'M';

    private static char[][] board = new char[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static int playerCol = INITIAL_PLAYER_COL;
    private static int playerRow = INITIAL_PLAYER_ROW;
    private static int nbrDoughnuts = 0;
    private static int nbrMoves = 0;
    private static Random random = new Random();

    private static int lives = 1;
    private static int doughnutLives;
    private static boolean doughnutCheck;
    static ArrayList<Move> movement = new ArrayList<Move>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        setUpBoard();
        showBoard();
        String opt;
        do {
            System.out.print("Next option ?");
            opt = scan.next();
            char opt1 = opt.charAt(0);
            if (opt1 == UP_MOVE_CHAR || opt1 == DOWN_MOVE_CHAR
                    || opt1 == LEFT_MOVE_CHAR || opt1 == RIGHT_MOVE_CHAR
                    || opt1 == UNDO_MOVE_CHAR) {
                move(opt1);
                //undoMove(opt1);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Allowed commands are: + " + UP_MOVE_CHAR
                        + "," + DOWN_MOVE_CHAR + "," + LEFT_MOVE_CHAR
                        + "," + RIGHT_MOVE_CHAR);
            }
            showBoard();
            System.out.println("Number of moves made = " + nbrMoves);
            System.out.println("Number of doughnuts eaten = " + nbrDoughnuts);
            System.out.println("Lives = " + lives);
        } while (board[HOME_ROW][HOME_COL] == HOME_CHAR);
        System.out.println("Thank you and goodbye");

    }

    /**
     * Set up the initial state of the board
     */
    private static void setUpBoard() {
        intialiseBoard(); // Fill the board with . characters
        //Add  the first vertical wall
        int v1StartCol = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 2);
        int v1StartRow = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - WALL_LENGTH - 1);
        addVerticalWall(v1StartCol, v1StartRow, WALL_LENGTH);

        //Add the second vertical wall
        int v2StartCol;
        do {
            v2StartCol = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 2);
        } while (v2StartCol == v1StartCol);
        int v2StartRow = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - WALL_LENGTH - 1);
        addVerticalWall(v2StartCol, v2StartRow, WALL_LENGTH);

        //Add the horizontal wall
        int h1StartRow = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 2);
        int h1StartCol = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - WALL_LENGTH - 1);
        addHorizontalWall(h1StartCol, h1StartRow, WALL_LENGTH);

        //Add the dougnuts
        int nbrDoughnutsAdded = 0;
        while (nbrDoughnutsAdded < 5) {
            int dRow = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 2);
            int dCol = 1 + random.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE - 2);
            if (board[dRow][dCol] == FREE_SQUARE_CHAR) {
                board[dRow][dCol] = DOUGHNUT_CHAR;
                nbrDoughnutsAdded++;
            }
        }

        //Add the player and the home square
        board[playerRow][playerCol] = PLAYER_CHAR;
        board[HOME_ROW][HOME_COL] = HOME_CHAR;
    }

    /**
     * Add a vertical wall to the board
     *
     * @param startCol Column on which wall is situated
     * @param startRow Row on which top of wall is situated
     * @param length Number of squares occupied by wall
     */
    private static void addVerticalWall(int startCol, int startRow, int length) {
        for (int row = startRow; row < startRow + length; row++) {
            board[row][startCol] = WALL_CHAR;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a horizontal wall to the board
     *
     * @param startCol Column on which leftmost end of wall is situated
     * @param startRow Row on which wall is situated
     * @param length Number of squares occupied by wall
     */
    private static void addHorizontalWall(int startCol, int startRow, int length) {
        for (int col = startCol; col < startCol + length; col++) {
            board[startRow][col] = WALL_CHAR;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the board
     */
    private static void showBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(board[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fill the board with FREE_SQUARE_CHAR characters.
     */
    private static void intialiseBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                board[row][col] = FREE_SQUARE_CHAR;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Move the player
     *
     * @param moveChar Character indicating the move to be made
     */
    private static void move(char moveChar) {
        int newCol = playerCol;
        int newRow = playerRow;

        switch (moveChar) {
            case UP_MOVE_CHAR:
                if (lives == 1) {
                    newRow--;
                } else if (lives > 1) {
                    int number = keyBoard.nextInt();
                    if (number <= lives) {
                        newRow = newRow - number;
                    } else {
                        checkLives();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case DOWN_MOVE_CHAR:
                if (lives == 1) {
                    newRow++;
                } else if (lives > 1) {
                    squareNumberPrompt();
                    int number = keyBoard.nextInt();
                    if (number <= lives) {
                        newRow = newRow + number;
                    } else {
                        checkLives();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case LEFT_MOVE_CHAR:
                if (lives == 1) {
                    newCol--;
                } else if (lives > 1) {
                    squareNumberPrompt();
                    int number = keyBoard.nextInt();
                    if (number <= lives) {
                        newCol = newCol - number;
                    } else {
                        checkLives();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case RIGHT_MOVE_CHAR:
                if (lives == 1) {
                    newCol++;
                } else if (lives > 1) {
                    squareNumberPrompt();
                    int number = keyBoard.nextInt();
                    if (number <= lives) {
                        newCol = newCol + number;
                    } else {
                        checkLives();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case UNDO_MOVE_CHAR:
                if (movement.size() > 1) {
                    movement.remove(movement.size() - 1);
                    System.out.println("The decreasing  size of the arraylist is now " + movement.size()); //Test Line
                } else if (movement.size() < 1) {
                    System.out.println("There is no move to be undone!");
                }
                break;
        }
        if (newRow < 0 || newRow >= BOARD_SIZE || newCol < 0 || newCol >= BOARD_SIZE) {
            System.out.println("Sorry that move takes you off the board!");
        } else {
            char dest = board[newRow][newCol];
            if (dest == WALL_CHAR) {
                System.out.println("Sorry you landed on a wall!");
            } else {
                nbrMoves++;
                if (dest == DOUGHNUT_CHAR) {
                    doughnutCheck = true;
                    nbrDoughnuts++;
                    doughnutLives++;
                    lives = (doughnutLives + 1);
                }
                board[playerRow][playerCol] = FREE_SQUARE_CHAR;
                playerCol = newCol;
                playerRow = newRow;
                board[playerRow][playerCol] = PLAYER_CHAR;
            }
        }
        movement.add(new Move(playerCol, playerRow, newCol, newRow, doughnutCheck));
        System.out.println("The increasing size of the arraylist is now " + movement.size()); //Test Line
    }

    public static void squareNumberPrompt() {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of squares to be moved");
    }

    public static void checkLives() {
        System.out.println("Invalid number! The number must be"
                + " equal to or less than the number of lives you have");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code, I think I know the problem. When you undo a move, you remove the last move in the ArrayList. The issue is, however, that you count undo as a move itself. So when you undo, then undo again, you "undo" the previous undo. For example, this console output after undoing shows how you increment back to three moves:

```
Next option ? Z // Do undo
The decreasing  size of the arraylist is now 2 // The old move is undone
The increasing size of the arraylist is now 3 // However, the undo is counted as a move
```

So then, subsequent calls to undo would simply repeat over and over, undoing your undos and then adding them back, basically getting stuck in a loop. To fix this, simply change

```
movement.add(new Move(playerCol, playerRow, newCol, newRow, doughnutCheck));
```

to have an if statement checking for the undo move and block it from being added to the array, which would look like:

```
if (moveChar != UNDO_MOVE_CHAR)
   movement.add(new Move(playerCol, playerRow, newCol, newRow, doughnutCheck));
```

EDIT: Also see @user7254424's answer, as his is another reason why you will have issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (movement.size() > 1) {
                movement.remove(movement.size() - 1);
                System.out.println("The decreasing  size of the arraylist is now " + movement.size()); //Test Line
            } else if (movement.size() < 1) {
                System.out.println("There is no move to be undone!");
            }
```

You don't account for when movement.size() == 1, this may be where your issue is.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have now accounted for it!